# React state does not update immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to make use of `react-otp-input` package by disabling the OTP input for 5 seconds if the OTP input value is reached. The issue I encounter is that the state does not get properly updated. I have prepared a Codesandbox example, which shows that the `otp` length is not calculated properly when you start deleting characters and is one state behind. What might cause this issue?

Codesandox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-rhodes-klqyhp?file=/src/App.js

**Updated:** This can not be placed in the useEffect hook, as the setInterval function never counts down!

Comment: I have tried utilizing the useCallback hook, which also has no effect. Try filling the OTP input, and then remove 2 characters :c

Comment: `if (otp.length + 1 === 6) {` needs to be placed in `useEffect` of `otp`. setState is an async function.

Comment: @Rajesh, how shall the countdown work then!!??

Comment: Updated your sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sinoussi-defu19

Comment: @Rajesh thanks a lot! This one worked, as  I have totally forgotten I can set those up multiple times! :))

Comment: If you would still like this question to be reopened, please put the code in the question itself.